# Integer Arraylist to JTextArea

Tags: java, swing, arraylist, jframe, integer

How would I add an integer ArrayList to a JTextArea. I've tried using .append but it won't work because my ArrayList isn't a String ArrayList. What I'm trying to do is display the user inputted numbers that go into the arraylist into a textarea.

```
    private void btnAddActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
    // TODO add your handling code here:

    //mark string to int converstion
    String m = this.txtStudentMark.getText();
    int mark = Integer.parseInt(m);
    //add new mark to list
    Collections.addAll(marks);
    marks.add(mark);


    // display marks
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int elem : marks){
        sb.append(marks !=null ? marks.toString() : " ");
    }
    txtASort.setText(sb.toString());
```

Comment: So how would you go about making a String of that list?

Comment: Please show your code, that will help you solving the issue fast

Comment: Create a method that simply loops over the list and append to a `StringBuffer` then append the `toString()` to the `text()` of the `TextArea`... This is very simple.

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
private void btnAddActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       

String m = this.txtStudentMark.getText();

/*
int mark = Integer.parseInt(m);
//add new mark to list
Collections.addAll(marks);
marks.add(mark);


// display marks
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int elem : marks){
    sb.append(marks !=null ? marks.toString() : " ");
} 


txtASort.setText(sb.toString()); */

txtASort.setText(txtASort.getText()+" "+m);
```